# Ordering chained "with" in laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm working with Laravel 8...

So I have the following eloquent query, I've eager loaded a bunch of models but I want to do 2 things to the way the models are loaded:

1. Only select certain fields from the cooking_methods model
2. Order the suppliers by a priority column, and take only the first one

```
$sales = $site->sales()
         ->with('recipes.cooking_methods.ingredient.suppliers')
         ->whereBetween('deliver_by',[$end,$start])
         ->where('status','pending')->get();
```

I've seen that you can attach a function to individual models but is there a way to attach them inline? Can't see it in the docs.

Any wizards on here that can help with that?

I've seen that you can attach a function to individual models but is there a way to attach them inline? Can't see it in the docs.

Any wizards on here that can help with that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not inline like that, but you can chain relationship subqueries. You'd have to do `->with(['recipes.cooking_methods' => function ($subQuery) { $subQuery->select(/* certain fields */)->with(['ingredient.suppliers' => function ($subSubquery) { $subSubQuery->orderBy('priority_column'); })]); })])->get()` (or something like that, pending any issues with brackets too). Laravel doesn't allow limiting a loaded relationship to "the first one", but you'd simply do `->suppliers->first()` when you need only the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this. Not tested. But Hopefully, this will work.

```
$site->sales()->with([
    'recipes' => function ($query) {
        $query->with([
            'cooking_methods' => function ($query) {
                $query->with(['ingredient.suppliers'])
                    ->select(['ingredient_id', 'field_1', 'field_2']); // ingredient_id for relation
            }
        ]);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) you can use an array in `->with` method, but you need write relationship in Sale Model, change `$site` for Sale Model with where clause.

The second point check [ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#ordering) `->orderBy('field','asc')` functions and use `->first()` method to get it. The Query builder methods works in ORM Models.